# How do I override the format type in a form for Rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My default format is set to json, as I want it to, however, i want to override it when a user submits a form from a website.

I would like to do the following in my form:

```
%form{ :method => 'POST', :action => a_path , options: [format: :html]}
```

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Isn't this based on respond_to and that rails does it automatically based on extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was:

```
%form{ :method => 'POST', :action => api_quizzes_path(format: :html)}
```